# need to get url attached to the tweet (status)

Tags: twitter

When I try to get the tweet (status) using this API endpoint 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=
the entities object which have urls does not provide me the link posted with the status, in the urls object there is only the tweet url itself.

example 
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1148391479490043910

in this status there is an attached url

https://www.realitytvworld.com/news/tyler-cameron-13-things-know-about-the-bachelorette-star-hannah-brown-bachelor-tyler-cameron--26081.php

the shortest one is

https://t.com/LtkuldDijy

I need to get this url mentioned above in the urls subobject of entities object

Does anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a ton of searches and tries, I got the reason

the issue was because of the truncate issue of the tweet itself,
so when request twitter API, must add 'tweet_mode=extended' to the request and everything work perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

[image: JSON Tweet in console]

The long url is in `thejson.entities.urls[0].expanded_url`

The short one is in `thejson.entities.urls[0].url`

Comment: Thanks JeffProd but when I request I see only the tweet's url itself in entities not the attached one  :(

Comment: can you provide me more details please ?

Comment: In your request, add `include_entities: true` : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Comment: the same result, and not for all statuses, some statuses have the actual posted URL, and others have the tweet's (status') URL in the entities. really strange issue.